# Using href to go to a show page with a specific id?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a link on my page that goes to a page with the right id. The page where the link is is at: `http://localhost:3000/quotes/9942/marketingScheduleShell`. Once the link is clicked the page should redirect to `http://localhost:3000/quotes/9942/`.

Something along these lines is how I want this to work but when I try the code below it just takes me to the `/quotes/` page.

```
<a href='http://localhost:3000/quotes/' + @quote.id>Show</a>
```

How can I use the id of the quote object I click on to go to the correct page for that object?

Comment: did you try Rails' `#link_to` helper method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only think you need is a `link_to` [method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

`link_to('Show', quote_path(@quote))`

Also reading some guides would save you a lot of time: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/